# Deploying a SPFx webparts to local SP server

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

We updated local SP server with latest features packages(2016)

I have created SPFx webpart with yeoman(yo @microsoft/sharepoint) 
and able to deploy SPO, and hello-world webpart look fine.

But when I try to deploy same to local server, it not works there main reason of it looks "valid package" column of webpart is No (it was Yes in SPO)

[image]
There is a ps in [official guide](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page) of sharepoint they say:

> Note: The SharePoint Framework is currently in preview and is subject
>   to change. SharePoint Framework client-side web parts are not
>   currently supported for use in production environments

Is it reason ? SPFx RC works only in SPO not local server ? it doesnt make sense but couldnt resolve this issue

Comment: It is still only available online

Comment: To add to Robert's comment, Microsoft has said that SPFX support will be included in some future Feature Pack for SharePoint 2016.

Comment: Keep as much as possible outside the SPFx MVC stack; eg. learn to use the toolchain, TypeScript, React etc. **without** using SPFx.  SPFx is (and should be) nothing more but a means to get your application delivered to a SharePoint page. That way you are ready for when SPFx goes GA (or ready for any non-SharePoint position in WWW LaLa land)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use npm v3 or v4, not higher, 
downgrade NPM
npm install -g npm@3
also,
npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.3